# What's wrong with CollectionColumn?

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I'm trying out `phantom` from outworkers following the laidout tut on the wiki.

I'm using a test model:

```
case class User (id: String, name: String, friends: List[String])
```

with:

```
import com.websudos.phantom.dsl._

class Users extends CassandraTable[Users, User] {
  object id extends StringColumn(this) with PartitionKey[String]
  object name extends StringCoumn(this)
  object friends extends ListColumn[String](this)
}
```

The `ListColumn[String]()` argument `this` is marked as an error which I presume I shouldnt even bother to build. Expected `CassandraTable[String, User]` instead of `this`.

I'm using version 1.29.6

Am I using a different version from the wiki example? Or missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an InteliJ highlightining problem. `ListColumn` is defined as a type alias inside Cassandra table, and for all type aliases that take constructor arguments, InteliJ is not capable of seeing through them.

That aside, I would really upgrade to phantom 2.0.0+, just because of all the new improvements made in 2.0.0. There is quite a bit of work that's gone into fixing errors and reducing how much code you need to type:

```
import com.outworkers.phantom.dsl._

class Users extends CassandraTable[Users, User] {
  object id extends StringColumn(this) with PartitionKey
  object name extends StringCoumn(this)
  object friends extends ListColumn[String](this)
}
```

In more recent versions of phantom, 2.9.x+, the `this` argument is no longer required using the new compact DSL.

```
import com.outworkers.phantom.dsl._

abtract class Users extends Table[Users, User] {
  object id extends StringColumn with PartitionKey
  object name extends StringColumn
  object friends extends ListColumn[String]
}
```